# Find element in array based off of two fields in object

Tags: javascript, algorithm

Given array

```js
const array = [
  {
    "state": "AK",
    "classCode": "ISO_11204",
    "territory": "1",
    "territoryLabel": "001 - Entire State",
    "finalPremOps": 0.27,
    "finalPCo": 0.6,
    "startDate": '1/1/2020',
    "endDate": '12/31/2020'
  },
  {
    "state": "AK",
    "classCode": "ISO_11204",
    "territory": "1",
    "territoryLabel": "001 - Entire State",
    "finalPremOps": 0.27,
    "finalPCo": 0.6,
    "startDate": '1/1/2021',
    "endDate": '12/31/2021'
  },
  {
    "state": "AK",
    "classCode": "ISO_11204",
    "territory": "1",
    "territoryLabel": "001 - Entire State",
    "finalPremOps": 0.27,
    "finalPCo": 0.6,
    "startDate": '1/1/2022',
    "endDate": null
  },
  ]
```

I'd like to create a function that will find the element that's in between start and end date given a current date.

If current date is past 1/1/2022, return the last element.
If current date is 1/2/2021, return the second element.
If current date is 1/2/2020, return the first element.

Comment: Can you give more information? How many objects would you have in your array? Is the array sorted? Can there be overlaps in date ranges? What if the "current" date fits in multiple ranges? What if the current date comes before the least `startDate`? And most importantly, what is holding you back to write the function you want to have? You didn't describe the problem you have with just implementing it...

Answer (score 0):

Just so I understand it correctly: you want to make a function that does this?

```
// non-optimized psuedocode:
function returnAllWithinDateRangeOf(currentDate) {
    let returnArray = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (array[i].startDate <= currentDate && currentDate <= array[i].endDate) {
            returnArray.push(array[i]);
        }
    }
    return returnArray;
}
```

I'm assuming your example was just to show that you wanted to return a subset of the array which fits the specified date range. If so, and if the array is small, then you can just use the code above (replacing the psuedocode parts).
Otherwise, if the array is quite large, then it's going to be tricky to get a fast result. If the array is large, can you find ways to shorten it? Ideally the data would be stored in a database, with a method to query the database. Ideally the method would allow you to specify filters to narrow down your results to just those you need (those within the date range in this case).